# Generate ERD Diagram from Sinatra/DataMapper

Tags: sinatra, entity-relationship, datamapper, diagram

Is there a way to generate ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram) from Sinatra/DataMapper, without Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [dm-visualizer](https://github.com/postmodern/dm-visualizer) gem.